# Constructing superharmonic functions

Tags: real-analysis, potential-theory

Suppose $U$ is an open set in $\mathbb{R}^n$ ($n>1$), and $u: U\to (-\infty,\infty]$ locally bounded below.  Suppose $u$ satisfies the superharmonic mean value inequality, i.e. for all ball $B(x,r)$ relatively compact in $U$, $u(x)$ is bounded below by the mean value of $u$ over the ball. In this case, this is a standard result that  the lower semi-continuous regularization of $u$, i.e.
$$u_*(x):=\liminf_{\substack{y\rightarrow x\\(u\in U)}}u(y),$$ is superharmonic on $U$.

I use this procedure and obtain incorrect results! Is there something else in the above result I mentioned that I am missing ?

Comment: Can you be more specific? How did you use that “standard result” and what incorrect results did you get?

Comment: For example, Armitage and Gardiner use in the proof of Theorem 3.7.5. in their "classical potential theory". But in fact, by construction $u_*$ is lower semi-continuous, and one can easily check that it satisfies the superharmonic mean inequality, since $u$ does.